# Sorting data in ResultSet Java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have obtained a ResultSet for some query, e.g:

```
select * from students order by roll
```

Now, is it possible to perform an equivalent of query

```
Select * from students order by dob;`
```

on the **ResultSet**?

Comment: no. Extract your data into a collection and sort.

Comment: May you give more details what you are trying to achieve and why ? Do you need a stable sort ? And no you cannot sort the RS directly or execute SQL queries against it

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I have large dataset and only one instance of the dataset will fit into memory. For high performance, I want the dataset be on memory. So sorting the data in memory is more desirable in my case.

Comment: Well, that's one more reason to do it in the DB, but if you don't want /cannot do it, then just map your result set to domain objects and work with them

Answer (score 5):

As rule of thumb (well, almost)  everything that can be done in the DB should be done there, so you should sort your data in the DB using the `... ORDER BY <column1>, <COLUMN2>... ASC/DESC`

But if for some reason you cannot do that you should extract all the data from the RS into a collection  (and may be map your data to domain objects) and sort it using the `Collections.sort()` method with  an appropriate `Comparator`

Answer (score 4):

It will be very not recommended to do the Sort after the query (ie. When you're getting the ResultSet).
You should always aim to do actions on the SQL Server rather on the code itself.

**ResultSet** are some kind of Iteration objects, that means that you can only move one by one. Thus, in order to Sort it, you first need to shift the data into a Collection and only then use Sorting on it.
Compare to SQL Sorting this is overhead and can be avoided.

Comment: @Olayinka, Added explanation on ResultSet

Answer (score 2):

Get an `ArrayList` from your `ResultSet` by iterating over your result and adding it to a a new list.
Then use`Collections.sort(Collection, Comparator)` to sort your result